# optimization tool

Tags: python, optimization, loops, loop-unrolling

I wonder there are any tool to optimize my program in term of loop unrolling, and how can I use it?

I have the following python code:

```
for i in range(0, 1000):
       a = a * 10 + a%4 + i
for j in range(0, 1000):
       j = j + a 
for b in range(0, 1000):
      result = j + b
```

I want to optimize this code segment so that I can try to understand loop unrolling a bit. With Python, I want to know a C optimizer.

Comment: Your code doesn't work (`a` is not defined). First make it work, then optimize.

Comment: I just tried to show code segment, not all. If you want add a = 30

Comment: The second loop can be replaced with `j = a + 999`. The third with `result = j + 999`.

Comment: @larsmans I don't think that's the doing what the OP *wants* to do.

Answer (score 4):

```
a = 30
for i in range ( 0,1000 ) :
    a = a * 10 + a%4 + i
```

can be rewritten as:

```
a = reduce(lambda a,b: a * 10 + a%4 + b, xrange(1000), 30)
```

takes about the same time (~4ms on my computer).

---

```
for j in range ( 0, 1000 ) :
       j = j + a
```

doesn't make much sense. You are iterating `j` over 0-999, and each time add your huge `a` to it, which is immediately forgotten, because next `j` is taken. It can be rewritten as:

```
j = 999 + a
```

---

```
for b in range ( 0 , 1000 ) :
      result = j + b
```

doesn't make much sense either. It is equivalent to:

```
result = j + 999
```

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't satisfied with the performance of your code, have profiled it, and found that low-level loops like this are a bottleneck, you should be able to speed up your code hugely by using [cython](http://cython.org) to turn the expensive bits of code into C extensions.  Also, if you are using python 2.x, you should be using `xrange` instead of `range`.

Comment: can you give example how can I use it ( cython )

Comment: The official documentation is very good.  Look at [getting started](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/index.html) for instructions on installing cython, building cython code (using `pyximport` is the easiest way), calling it from python, and speeding up code using static type declarations.  Instructions for `pyximport` are [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#compilation).

Answer (score 2):

There exists a scientific paper regarding effects of loop unrolling in Python ([pdf link](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1534550)). [These](http://cs.haifa.ac.il/~rotemn/talks/google.pdf) are the slides of the related talk.

However, in terms of automatic C code optimization you can use [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) in combination with [LooPo](https://www.infosun.fim.uni-passau.de/cl/loopo/) and possibly [Polly](https://polly.llvm.org/). Anyway, LLVM is a good starting point.

Comment: CAn you give example how to use it ( llvm )

Comment: This is a course guide: Use LLVM to generate bytecode from your C-code (e. g. with `clang -emit-llvm -c foo.c -o foo.o`) and use one or more of [these](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html) transform passes. The result is again readable bytecode or even graphs (created with graphviz). You can give it a try, but you'll have to invest some time and don't expect miracles ;)

Comment: I searched this file with .deb format but I couldn't found any file in ubuntu package. Have you used them in ubuntu

Comment: You'll have to compile LLVM on your own. Read the documentation careful. Starting point is llvm.org